# Nokia Remote Device Access

Tags: windows-phone-8, tcp, firewall, nokia, windows-firewall

I am not able to launch the Nokia RDA, Getting this error message:

Unable to initiate server communication. Please verify that you do not have firewall software preventing the Remote Device Access process (javaw.exe) from accessing apu.ndhub.net, TCP port 1,200.

I am afraid how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

In order to use that, Check these requirements

- JavaScript must be enabled.
- Browser must be Firefox v2+, Internet Explorer v7+, Opera v9.6+ or Safari v3.
- Java Web Start must be installed.

If the problem persist, please check your Java installed version is up to date and also your browser belongs to the version required. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Also, I have tried Keeping Windows Firewall off but it also didn't worked.

Comment: Whats your java version currently now? It should be Version 7 Update 65. https://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Comment: Are you sure that you are satisfying the above conditions? If yes, am sorry that i don't know whats your problem exactly is? Try posting this question also in Nokia Developer site. You may get an answer.